# How to capture all ActiveRecord::Errors under config/initializersin Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, error-handling

I am trying to configure my applications to print errors from any ActiveRecord object in my app. So that I can avoid printing the error message for each object in all place of transactions. Is there any way to do this?

Need somethind like this

in config/initializers

```
ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
   # For each active_record object in my app
   if self.errors.any?
      puts self.errors.inspect
   end
end
```

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking... can you give us an example of the behaviour you expect? possibly even some pseudo-code?

Comment: Again - this doesn't seem to make sense to me... when do you want the puts to be called? The reason I ask is that errors only exist on individual instances of an Active Record... and only fleetingly. This second there's an error, because somebody tried to update, say the username of a User model - but it was too short... but the next second - the user has abandoned the edit, or fixed the mistake - and the errors are gone.... when o you want to do this error-check?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to have all the AR errors in one place,

One method would be using `rescue_from`. Simply you could do something like this in your application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base 
   protect_from_forgery with: :exception

   #your normal code

   rescue_from Exception do |exeception|
      #check if this is a AR exception
      #if yes then
      #log it in a different log file
      #if not
      # yield (to follow the default exception chain)
   end
end
```

more proper way would be to have this in a module and `include` it in `ApplciationController`.

HTH